# Which payment procedure should I follow for selling digital content as well as physical book in my IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, credit-card

I have successfully made an app which is basically for exam preparation. In a further update I need to implement In app purchases (IAP) to sell digital content like on-line test series within app. But, within the app there is already a section that is used to sell physical books. Selling physical items is not allowed as per Apple guidelines for IAP.

Should I go for IAP, use a payment gateway, or do I have to use both?

Comment: You will need two payment solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct,

For digital content purchase you need to go with IAP which is mandatory as per Apple guideline.

For selling of physical books you can use third party payment gateways like PayPal, etc.

Comment: Means, I can use both (IAP & Paypal) in my app?
Hope, this will be as per Apple guideline.

Comment: yes we can not use in app purchase except digital content, so for physical goods we can use any third party payment gateway.